# go resolve (not yet) remote dependencies during development

Tags: go, dependencies, go-modules

I'm developing a go module, let's call it `github.com/spyna/mymodule`.

This module is a library and another go project uses it, for example: `github.com/spyna/goapp` uses `github.com/spyna/mymodule`.

During the development phase, I don't want to push changes in `github.com/spyna/mymodule` because they're still under development, but in order to test the changes, I want to use the local version of `github.com/spyna/mymodule` as a dependency of `github.com/spyna/goapp`.

For example, this file in `github.com/spyna/goapp` requires `github.com/spyna/mymodule`.

```
//main.go

package main

import (
    "github.com/spyna/mymodule"
)

func main() {
 mymodule.doSomething()
}
```

If I run this code, the dependency is resolved remotely, but I want to use the local one, to test my changes.

Is this possible in go?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `replace` directives in `go.mod`. In your `go.mod` add:

```
 replace github.com/spyna/mymodule => ../path/to/local/mymodule
```

See the [replace specification](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace)

Comment: Thank you, this works! Is there any other not manual method to do this? I mean, when the development phase is finished, I need to remember to remove the `replace`.

Comment: There a command line tool `go mod edit` (see `go mod help edit`) that can perform these transformations. But you have to remember to roll back. A linter could check that there is no replace directive in `go.mod`

Comment: @Spyna: just don't commit the `replace` line, so there's nothing to roll back.